# How to access value of the global variable in other function javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is one of the similar example

```
var global=0;
function somefunction()
{
    global++;
}

var temp=global;
function somefunctiontwo()
{
    var x=temp;
}
```

here I am getting x=0
I want x=1

how can I assign newly assigned value of global variable to x

Comment: where are you calling somefunction to add to global?

Comment: are you actually calling somefunction before assigning temp = global?

Comment: somefunction() is called in document.ready() function and somefunctiontwo() is called on click event

Comment: I assume you want to access the value of the global variable through the temp variable, right? If so, see my answer below. Issue is the 'reference by value' of the number type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an object as global variable; that will be assigned by reference instead of 'by value' as for the simple (number) type:

```
var global = { value: 0 };

var temp = global;
```

in function:

```
global.value++;
```

now is:

```
temp.value == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`temp` and `global` refer to two different variables.  Assigning to `global` will not change the value in `temp`.

Simply change `var x=temp` to `var x=global`.  It's not clear why you need an intermediate variable.

Comment: Tried but still value is 0 i want increamented value of global variable

Comment: @jeetZ Then paste the exact code you are executing; the code in your question is incomplete (you never call either function).  It's difficult to diagnose code we cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

```
var global=0;
var temp;
function somefunction(){
  global++;
}



function somefunctiontwo() {
    var x=temp;
    console.log(x);
}

somefunction();
temp=global;
somefunctiontwo();
```

This will give what you expect. Pay attention on how/where you call the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure seems a little off, not sure if this is for a reason we can't see... Will presume it is. Can have a function that resyncs the temp value to global.

```
function syncGlob(){
    return temp = global;
}
```

Returns temp as well so you can call it when creating x.

```
var x = syncGlob();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the value of temp to global PRIOR to the on ready firing - at this point global is 0.  If you increment global at on ready, temp already has a value of 0.

When you click somefunction2 and assign x the value of temp, temp has a value of 0, because at the time of temp initiation, global had a value of 0 NOT 1